# Heroku don't want to refer my django models to views

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am deploying my [django](/questions/tagged/django) application on [heroku](/questions/tagged/heroku) and I have this error :

```
DatabaseError: referenced relation "question_view" is not a table
```

I am using a postgresql database where question_view is a view. I have not this problem when I run the application locally.
Could someone please explain what is this error please ?

Comment: Did you sync the DB after pushing to Heroku?

Comment: The error come when I try to sync the db via the command `heroku run python manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 1):

I bypassed the problem by comment my models which reffered to views, and then sync the database (to create tables needed for administration).